# An optimal way of nginx rewrite rule building for pretty URL

Tags: nginx, rewrite, url

The webpage is accessed in the following way:

```
`example.com/` or `example.com/?site=website`
```

In this example, I'm accessing the **websites** located on **example.com** domain.

Could anyone suggest an optimal way of rewriting rules, so the above would be shown and accessed by `example.com/website`, or just `example.com/` if no `site` is sent?

nginx, Centos 7

**UPDATE**

Tried the following:

```
location / {
    index index.php;
    rewrite ^/(website)$ /site?$1;
}
```

Comment: Serverfault is not a configuration writing service.

Comment: But where should I write this?

Comment: I would vote to close, but I can't because of the bounty. "Questions should demonstrate reasonable business information technology management practices".

Comment: It seems like you recent updates to the question actually make it LESS clear — you originally was saying that the `site` string was a parameter (`?site=`), now you're saying it's an URI (`/site`).  So, which one is it?  The correct way to write any software is to first have a spec.  If you have absolutely no spec that you could articulate, and only an account what doesn't work (but no account of what was supposed to happen, and what does work), then you won't get anywhere, even if you do ask other folks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost an identical question just a couple of weeks ago:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45257380/nginx-rewrite-query-string-args-to-html-url-w-o-backend-support/45293264#45293264

https://gist.github.com/cnst/3521404dfdf5cb7b4c526b5c6dff38ff

```
location = / {
    if ($arg_site) {
        return  302 /$arg_site;
    }
    return  200
    "<!DOCTYPE html><title>site</title>
    <form><input name='site' value='website'/></form>\n";
}
location / {
    rewrite     ^/([^/]*)\$     /?site=$1   break;
    proxy_pass  http://localhost:7381;
}
```

The idea is you create a redirect loop, but not really, since there is a difference between external v. internal redirects, so, the loop is not a closed one, because one redirect is explicitly only external, whereas the other one is explicitly only internal.

Comment: It gave  socket() failed (24: Too many open files) while connecting to upstream

Comment: It sounds like you may be doing a proxy_pass to the very same server; you must do a proxy_pass to your actual backend, 100% distinct from the configuration at stake; if it's still nginx that's doing backend work for you, then you must use appropriate `fastcgi_pass` et al in place of `proxy_pass`.  Please note that this configuration works 100% if your problem is any similar to what the other poster was having.  Your question has very little info to know what exactly is it that you want, and what is actually working.  If nothing at all works, and you have no idea what's going on — hire someone.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. Basically it captures the string after the slash, before the end of the string, and calls site with that string as the parameter

```
location /
  rewrite ^/(website)$ /site?$1;
}
```

The browser needs to use a URL such as http://example.com/abcd , internally Nginx will call http://example.com/site=abcd  . You obviously need to have a location set up that will respond to requests on that url. For example

```
location /site
  proxy_pass localhost:1234;
}
```

I did a test using a plain Nginx configuration, which only differs from the above with the .html extension required for the test.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name test1.example.com;

  location / {
    root /var/www/test1;
    rewrite ^/(website).html$ /site.html?$1;
  }    
}
```

I created two files, website.html and site.html, with contents being their filename. Without the rewrite the browser shows "website". With the rewrite it shows "site". This proves to me the test configuration works.

Comment: Updated question, adding more details

Comment: The rewrite I gave you earlier works as per your edit when the URL doesn't contain the substring "website". Did you try it?

Comment: No, that didn't work for me

Comment: Updated the description

Comment: That's because your configuration is really quite incorrect. You shouldn't have the php location nested inside the root location. You should really be hiring someone to do this, not asking for help on Server Fault, we can't teach you Nginx configuration.

Comment: Ok, I removed it from there. Nothing changed. Updated description

Comment: Two problems here 1) You don't have a location to handle the site URL 2) Saying "doesn't work" is completely useless - you need to edit your question (not reply to a comment) to show a curl, the access logs, describe what happened, and why it isn't what you want. I believe I've answered your question, you can't keep changing it to try to get someone to build a full configuration for you when you don't understand Nginx at all.